# answer is undefined when a spacebar is entered within the answer

Tags: javascript, undefined

When a spacebar is inputted in the prompt, the program will read the answer as "undefined" rather than going through the while loop as I want it to. I tried adding "number==undefined" to the while loop but it didn't solve the issue.

```
var name = new Array;
var number;
var i;
name[0] = "John";
name[1] = "Jeff";
name[2] = "Jake";
name[3] = "James";
for(i=0;i<=1;i++)
    {
    number = prompt("Name a number between 0-3:");
    while(!(number<=3) || !(number>=0) || parseInt(number)!==parseInt(number))
        {
        alert("Invalid answer.");
        number = prompt("Name your number again:");
        }
    document.write("You have chosen the name "+name[number]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is most likely based around the fact that `name` is a reserved word in JavaScript. But just in case you still see the issue, change these lines:

```
number = prompt("Name a number between 0-3:");
number = prompt("Name your number again:");
```

to these:

```
number = prompt("Name a number between 0-3:").trim();
number = prompt("Name your number again:").trim();
```

That will get rid of whitespace at the front and end of the string.

Comment: Quality. The only thing is that I'm creating a big program for this project, so would I have to add the .trim() at the end of every prompt?

Comment: No, you don’t have to add `trim` everywhere. You could have a central function that processes responses. Something along the lines of `const ask = q => prompt(q).trim();`

Answer (score 0):

`name` is a reserved keyword in javascript. So create a variable with different name. This may not have anything to do with space

```js
var nameArray = new Array;
var number;
var i;
nameArray[0] = "John";
nameArray[1] = "Jeff";
nameArray[2] = "Jake";
nameArray[3] = "James";
for (i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
  number = prompt("Name a number between 0-3:");
  while (!(number <= 3) || !(number >= 0) || parseInt(number) !== parseInt(number)) {
    alert("Invalid answer.");
    number = prompt("Name your number again:");
  }
  document.write("You have chosen the name " + nameArray[number]);
}
```